# Is there a better solution for this?? Python Pandas BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm curious if I got the easiest way.
I want to scrape a table from wikipedia and transfer it into a pandas dataframe (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Hochschulen_in_Deutschland).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Hochschulen_in_Deutschland")
soup = bs(r.content)
table = soup.find("table")
ths = table.find_all("th")

h = []
headers = []
for th in ths:
    th = th.get_text().split("\n")[0]
    h.append(th)
for th in h:
    th = th.split("- ")
    if len(th) > 1:
        th = th[0] + th[1]
    else:
        th = th[0]
    headers.append(th)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
```

It works (I got a `df` with the right column names), but i think there got to be a better way.

Here is the list "ths", so you dont have to run all of this.

```
 </th>,
 <th>Land
 </th>,
 <th>Form
 </th>,
 <th>Träger
 </th>,
 <th>Promotions-<br/> recht
 </th>,
 <th>Grün-<br/> dung
 </th>,
 <th>Studierende
 </th>,
 <th>Stand
 </th>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html), and let them do the webscraping:

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Hochschulen_in_Deutschland')
df = dfs[0] # select the first table read
```

Comment: First part of code worked great, but i dont quite get the second one.

Comment: Sorry about that - I thought from your code you might just be trying to initialize an empty dataframe with the same columns.  But I will remove for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'better', but you can use list comprehensions to make it slightly more pythonic:

`h = [th.get_text().split("\n")[0] for th in ths]`

can replace your first loop. Maybe you can see if you could replace your second loop with something similiar.